# Django - Database is empty after running migrations

Tags: django, django-models, pycharm, django-migrations

When I try to migrate my models to the default sql database in django, using pycharm, the db is empty after running migrations. This problem occurs with all my projects.

My app is called demoapp.

I have ran the following commands in the pycharm terminal, with these results:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'demoapp':
  demoapp\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Question
    - Create model User
```

```
python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, demoapp, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying demoapp.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

Yet, after these two commands, the db database in the database window in pycharm is empty and underlined red, while it should actually show the correct schema.

Comment: Do you mean the sqlite3 database?

Comment: yeah, the sqlite3 database

Comment: sqlite3 driver is missing. You can install it by the help of PyCharm

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe that cost me so much time

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody stumble with this issue using the SQLtools plugin in VScode.
If you move your database (deliberately or by accident)  to a new location remember to update the connection.
Just ***drop your current connection and create a new one..*** even if the connection test work but you're not getting your changes reflected.

And although this is an opinion and should not be part of the answer I think VScode should confirm when you move directories because you can create a mess unintentionally just because a drag and drop functionality that loves to drag everything everywhere